# Having issues with live calculations, calculating each key stroke

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table that calculates a total depending on the input the user types. My problem is that the jquery code is calculating each key stroke and not "grabbing" the entire number once you stop typing. Code is below, any help woud be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input.refreshButton').bind('click', EstimateTotal);
$('input.seatNumber').bind('keypress', EstimateTotal);
$('input.seatNumber').bind('change', EstimateTotal);
```

});

```
//$('input[type=submit]').live('click', function() {
function EstimateTotal(event) {
    var tierSelected = $(this).attr('data-year');
    var numberSeats = Math.floor($('#numberSeats_' + tierSelected).val());

    $('.alertbox_error_' + tierSelected).hide();
    if (isNaN(numberSeats) || numberSeats == 0) {
        $('.alertbox_error_' + tierSelected).show();
    } else {
        $('.alertbox_error_' + tierSelected).hide();

        var seatHigh = 0;
        var seatLow = 0;
        var seatBase = 0;
        var yearTotal = 0;
        var totalsArray = [];
        var currentYear = 0;

        $('.tier_' + tierSelected).each(function() {
            seatLow = $(this).attr('data-seat_low');
            firstSeatLow = $(this).attr('data-first_seat_low');
            seatHigh = $(this).attr('data-seat_high');
            seatBase = $(this).attr('data-base_cost');
            costPerSeat = $(this).attr('data-cost_per_seat');
            years = $(this).attr('data-year');
            seats = 0;

            if (years != currentYear) {
                if (currentYear > 0) {
                    totalsArray[currentYear] = yearTotal;
                }
                currentYear = years;
                yearTotal = 0;
            }

            if (numberSeats >= seatHigh) {
                seats = Math.floor(seatHigh - seatLow + 1);
            } else if (numberSeats >= seatLow) {
                seats = Math.floor(numberSeats - seatLow + 1);
            }

            if (seats < 0) {
                seats = 0;
            }
            yearTotal += Math.floor(costPerSeat) * Math.floor(seats) * Math.floor(years) + Math.floor(seatBase);
        });

        totalsArray[currentYear] = yearTotal;

        totalsArray.forEach(function(item, key) {
            if (item > 1000000) {
                $('.totalCost_' + tierSelected + '[data-year="' + key + '"]').append('Contact Us');
            } else {
                $('.totalCost_' + tierSelected + '[data-year="' + key + '"]').append('$' + item);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try wrapping everything in your calculation function in a setTimout(function(){ //code here}, 100);, with 100 milliseconds or less. It will give your function a split second to calculate, and the user won't see any lag depending on your time set.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a `setTimeout`, and a way to kill/reset it on the keypress.

I'd personally do something like this:

```
var calc_delay;
$(document).ready(function() {
$('input.refreshButton').bind('click', runEstimateTotal);
$('input.seatNumber').bind('keypress', runEstimateTotal);
$('input.seatNumber').bind('change', runEstimateTotal);
});

function runEstimateTotal(){
    clearTimeout(calc_delay);
    calc_delay = setTimeout(function(){ EstimateTotal(); }, 100);
}

function EstimateTotal() {
    ....
```

What this does is prompt the system to calculate 100ms after every keypress - unless another event is detected (i.e. runEstimateTotal is called), in which case the delay countdown resets.

Comment: Note that this will need to be elaborated/improved if you actually need to use the event data - that can be a bit tricky the way this is set up. But for the function you provided, this should suffice.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried adding the function and it didn't work. I made slight changes and it is now calculating correctly. The main change was changing the keypress event to keyup.